On the homotopy type of compact Lie groups and subgroups
In the article "The homotopy type of compact Lie groups" by Hubbuck, J. R., and R. M. Kane (1985), the authors present an alternative proof for a result by Hans Scheerer (1968), which states that if two compact, connected, and simply connected Lie groups have the same homotopy type, then they are isomorphic. Therefore, my question is whether it is possible to find examples where $G$ is a closed  subgroup of a compact Lie group $H$, both connected, but not simply connected, with the same homotopy type but not isomorphic.
Additionally, under these hypothesis, is it possible for the inclusion $i:G\to H$ to be a weak homotopy equivalence, with  $\dim G < \dim H$?

Hint: Think about top-dimensional homology groups of $G$ and $H$.

Sure, the homotopy equivalence will induce an isomorphism in homology/cohomology. Thank you! But regarding the first question, I still don't have an answer.

Think again about my hint, how can it help with your question. What will be top-dimensional homology of $H$, say, $H_t(H)$, and what will be  $H_t(G)$ if $G$ is a proper subgroup of $H$?

Certainly, I already realized what I was overlooking... of course, they must have the same dimension and therefore be isomorphic. The issue would only be relevant in this case if $G$ were not a subgroup of $H$.

I thought you are assuming that $G$ is a closed subgroup. Are you considering general subsets? General closed subsets? General subsets homeomorphic to Lie groups? Please edit your question to make this clear.

No, the statement is correct. I only meant that it might be more interesting to try finding a counterexample to Hans Scheerer's result in the case where the spaces are not simply connected (with two groups that are not necessarily subgroups of each other). In any case, I’d like to thank you for your help!
